# Cancel solution closing event in VS extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

In the package I'm trying to build I'm registering to the "BeforeClosing" event in the following way:

```
DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
dte.Events.SolutionEvents.BeforeClosing += SolutionEvents_BeforeClosing;
```

and the event handler looks like this:

```
private void SolutionEvents_BeforeClosing()
{
    //Check some stuff
    //Cancel the close operation
}
```

Is it possible to cancel the closing of the solution from within the event handler (something like `e.Cancel = true;`)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `QueryCloseSolution` solution event -- the event handler gets passed the reference to a boolean variable which must be set to `true` in order to abort the current closing attempt.